# How to integrate Razorpay Payment in flutter for iOS device

Tags: java, flutter, dart

This is my terminal output when I used "pod update" to install Razorpay plugin for iOS device.
I tried many times but not solved yet so give me any solution.

pod update
WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "razorpay_flutter":
In Podfile:
razorpay_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/razorpay_flutter/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `razorpay_flutter (from` .symlinks/plugins/razorpay_flutter/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your ios project using Xcode on mac.

And then try building it.

The same has solved the issue for me